# How to efficiently choose methods in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

[image]

I recently compute it.

```
NIntegrate[
 Boole[(x + y - z)^4 + 
    4 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - x*y + x*z + y*z)^2 \[LessSlantEqual] 
   9 Sqrt[3] z], {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 2}, {z, -1, 2}]
```

and i get 2.4686

the right answer is
[image]

which is equal to 2.59376.

`(Sqrt[(Sqrt[5]-1) 2]+ArcTan[Sqrt[(Sqrt[5]+1)/2]])*Pi/3//N`

I tried to apply different methods manually to get a better result. But since this calculation is time-consuming. So I wonder : is there any way to calculate it / select the method efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to polar coordinates.

```
gl = (x + y - z)^4 + 4 (x^2 - x y + y^2 + x z + y z + z^2)^2 <= 
9 Sqrt[3] z /. {x -> r Cos[phi] Sin[theta], 
y -> r Sin[phi] Sin[theta], z -> r Cos[theta]} // Expand
```

and apply `Reduce` to see the structure with a litte trick

```
red41=Reduce[gl && r > 0 && 0 < phi < 2 Pi && 0 < theta < Pi, r, 
Reals]//Simplify[#, r > 0 && 0 < phi < 2 Pi && 0 < theta < Pi] &;

red42 = red41 /. Root[__] -> root

(*   2 theta < \[Pi] && ((phi == \[Pi] && 
 r <= root) || 
(r <= root && (phi - \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi]) \[NotElement] Integers)) *}
```

It shows, r has to be integrated from 0 to the last root-term which is the surface of the inequation changed to an equation.

```
rr[phi_, theta_] = 
   r /. Solve[Equal @@ gl, r, Reals][[2]] // 
          Simplify[#, Cos[theta] != 0] &
```

By the way you get a fine Plot with

```
SphericalPlot3D[rr[phi, theta], {theta, 0, Pi/2}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Integration of r^3/3 over phi and the demanded theta < Pi/2 yields the desired result very fast.

```
NIntegrate[1/3 rr[phi, theta]^3*Sin[theta], 
     {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, {theta, 0, Pi/2}]

{*   2.59376   *}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[(x + y - z)^4 + 4 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - x*y + x*z + y*z)^2 <= 
    9 Sqrt[3] z], {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 2}, {z, -1, 2}, 
  Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo", MaxPoints -> 1000000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.286305, 2.58507}

Answer (score 3):

Your limits of integration may be contributing to the inaccuracy.  When we use the `SphericalPlot3D` as suggested by @Akku14 and superpose a `Cuboid` that represents the original limits of integration, we see that two regions that are outside the limits.

```
Show[{SphericalPlot3D[rr[phi, theta],
   {theta, 0, Pi/2}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}],
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[4/5], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {2, 2, 2}]}]},
 ViewPoint -> 2 {-1, -1, 1}, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Adjusting the limits of integration based on the graphics, and using the `Method` suggested by @OkkesDulgerci gives

```
NIntegrate[
  Boole[(x + y - z)^4 + 
     4 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - x*y + x*z + y*z)^2 \[LessSlantEqual] 
    9 Sqrt[3] z], {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}, {z, -1, 2},
  Method -> "QuasiMonteCarlo", MaxPoints -> 10^6] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.267952, 2.59402}  *)
```